# Codeigniter active record query cached - look for old table name instead of new one

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, caching, activerecord

I have project with 3 application's sharing one codeigniter installation. It was working excellent until I changed name of mysql table, and changed query to reflect new changes to the database. Now it looks like my insert query is cached, and trying to insert value into old table (which doesn't exist anymore). This is what I've tried so far:

CI:

```
$this->db->cache_delete_all()
```

mysql:

```
RESET QUERY CACHE;
```

In config/database.php:

```
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE; 
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
```

When db_debug configuration is set to TRUE it gives 500 error, when FALSE, I was able to catch error and it turn's out it's trying to insert into old table that doesn't exist anymore. I don't get how is this possible, I've even searched my complete project and can't find old table name anywhere in my project, also CI cache folders are empty. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: My insert code:

```
if($this->db->insert('booking_calendar', $data))
{
    $booking_id = $this->db->insert_id();           
    $this->load->helper('string');


    $order_id = strtoupper(random_string('alnum', 6)) . $booking_id;


    $data = array(
      'id'                  => $order_id,
      'booking_calendar_id' => $booking_id,
      'status'              => 'PAYMENT_PENDING'                            
    );

    if($this->db->insert('bookings', $data))
    {
        $this->notifications->add($MYSELF['id'], 'Court successfully booked.');
        return $order_id;   
    }

    $this->notifications->add($MYSELF['id'], 'Court booking failed.', 'warning');
    return false;
}
else
{               
    log_message('ERROR', 'Insert booking_calendar failed. ' . print_r($this->db->_error_message(), true));
}
```

And this is the output in my log:

```
ERROR - 2013-09-23 20:05:13 --> Insert booking_calendar failed. Table 'tennis.courts_calendar' doesn't exist
```

Notifications is custom class which just insert one row in "notifications" table.

Comment: post your insert code - most likely you've missed changing something there

Comment: @jmadsen I've edited my question to include insert code, sorry for late answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer to my problem, I had **ON BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE** triggers on my table, and when I changed it's name it turns out that inserting on the same table with new name was still triggering old table name instead of new one. So I just updated triggers and now it's working. Hope this will save time for someone else, because it took me a while even if it's looking trivial from this point of view now.